# Odd Palindrome generator (0 to 25000)

Tags: java, numbers, palindrome

How to get odd palindrome numbers between 0 to 25000?
I have not any idea for this problem. (Sorry for my english)

```
class Pal{
   public static void main(){
    //code here ;-(
   }
}
```

Comment: @VeeraKannadiga pls help

Comment: what have you actually tried yourself? you need to show us a [mcve] at the very least.

Comment: Did you search in Google? you will get lot of results!

Comment: @MacroMan I don't know how to do it

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think, this is program you are searching for.

```
 public class Palindrome {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for(int i=0;i<=25000;i++){
                int number=i;
                int reverse=0;
                int temp=0;
                while(number>0){
                    temp=number%10;
                    number=number/10;
                    reverse=reverse*10+temp;
                   // System.out.println(rev);
                    if(i==reverse){
                    if(reverse%2!=0){
                        System.out.println(reverse);
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't answer bad "do my work for me" questions.